# "The view or its master was not found error." But my intent is to not look for the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, actionresult

I obviously have this coded wrong.  My "addmenuItems" action method is not supposed to return an "addmenuItems" view, which should be apparent in my code below.

I am trying to return the view "follower", so why is it looking for "addmenuitems"?

```cs
public ActionResult AddMenuItems(List<int> MenuItemID, int? FollowerID)
{
    Follower follower = new Follower();
    if (FollowerID == null)
    {
        return View(follower);
    }
    else
    {
        follower = db.Followers.Find(FollowerID);
        follower.MenuItems.Where(m => !MenuItemID
            .Contains(m.MenuItemID))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Remove(m));
        var existingMenuItemIds = follower.MenuItems.Select(m => m.MenuItemID).ToList();
        db.MenuItems.Where(m => MenuItemID.Except(existingMenuItemIds)
            .Contains(m.MenuItemID))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Add(m));
        return View(follower);   
    }
}
```

And below here is the View:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMenuItems", "Merchants", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Follow these Menu Items</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the view name (otherwise it uses the view which is the same name as the method) - `return View("follower", follower);`

Comment: Excellent, knew it would be something simple like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `return View(model)` will display the view with the same name as your action method. To specify a different view, the it needs to be

```
return View("follower", follower);
```

where the first parameter is the name of the view.

Comment: So if the view "followers" is not in the Shared folder or the Merchant folder, how do I use this parameter to find the "followers" view.  Or more specifically the "details" view, under the "followers" folder?

Comment: Hmmm....  Just thought of a solution.  I should probably move this entire Action Method out of my Merchants controller and into my Followers controller.  Gonna try that first.